# 'ls' showing two identical files in a directory

Tags: bash, osx, ls

So somehow the command `ls` seems to be showing me two identical files in a directory.

```
$ ls -Blah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
total 32                                                              
drwxr-xr-x  266 root  wheel   8.8K Jun 18 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x   79 root  wheel   2.6K Mar 31 12:28 ..
[redacted]
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   715B Jun 18 10:36 tftp.plist
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   715B Jun 18 10:35 tftp.plist
```

I can move, rename, edit etc. one of the files, but the other one does not even seem to be there. `bash` tab completion even shows identical files.

For example, entering the following and then hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
$ sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp
tftp.plist   tftp.plist
```

If I rename the file:

```
$ sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist.derp
```

The tab completion still shows the file:

```
$ ls -Blah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tf
tftp.plist       tftp.plist.derp
```

But the original, unmodified file does not appear to 'ls'

```
$ ls -Blah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist
ls: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist: No such file or directory
```

However if I just list the files as in the first code snippet above, behold:

```
$ ls -Blah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
total 32                                                              
drwxr-xr-x  266 root  wheel   8.8K Jun 18 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x   79 root  wheel   2.6K Mar 31 12:28 ..
[redacted]
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   715B Jun 18 10:35 tftp.plist
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   715B Jun 18 10:36 tftp.plist.derp
```

Any idea what's going on here and how I can get rid of this ghost file?

This is a mac running OS X if that adds any info to the problem. I was using `sed` on this file just before the craziness began.

### Edit

I have used both the `blah` and the `Blah` `ls` flags with no change in apparent output.

### Edit 2

Additional info requested in comments:

```
$ echo tftp* | xxd
0000000: 7466 7470 2e70 6c69 7374 2020 7466 7470  tftp.plist  tftp
0000010: 2e70 6c69 7374 2e64 6572 700a            .plist.derp.
```

More:

```
$ printf '<%q>\n' tftp*
<tftp.plist\ >
<tftp.plist.derp>
```

Even more:

```
$ locale                                                                                                                      │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   495B Sep  9  2014 org.net-snmp.snmpd.plist
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                            │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   498B Jan 15 23:15 org.ntp.ntpd.plist
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                      │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   1.0K Nov 13  2014 org.openldap.slapd.plist
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                        │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   572B Sep  9  2014 org.postfix.master.plist
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                     │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   238B Sep  9  2014 shell.plist
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                     │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   941B Sep  9  2014 ssh.plist
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                      │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   260B Sep  9  2014 telnet.plist
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"                                                                                                         │-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   715B Jun 18 10:36 tftp.plist
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

### Note

The answer below helped me see that there was a trailing space in the name.

Comment: Could it be that you have a trailing space in the name?

Comment: Hmmm… No, completion will do `ls test\ `… What happen if you use `ls "*tftp.list*"`? or use `ls` with `--show-control-chars`?

Comment: Can you run something like `echo tftp* | xxd` or some other hexdump?

Comment: So with the editable file renamed to `tftp.plist.derp` still, `ls -blah tftp.plist*` shows both files while `ls -blah tfpt.plist` shows no files.

Comment: @choroba I'll add that to the question.

Comment: What's the output of `printf '<%q>\n' tftp*`?

Comment: @ChrisDown Added to Question. Looks like there is a training space hiding here. Any idea why `ls` did not escape this with the `b` or `B` flags??

Comment: If `isprint(' ')` is true in your locale, `ls -b` won't print anything special.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick i am intrigued by your comment, however I don't follow you. Can you let me know how I can check this to see what the value of this locale setting is?

Comment: What's the output of `locale LANG`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick added to question. Really interested in how I can get `ls` to work as I expected when handling trailing whitespace. Thanks.

Comment: Since your locale is `en_US.UTF-8`, `ls -b` will not show blanks in filenames in any special way, whether in the middle or at the end of the filename. You can use one of the answers (printf, echo), or filter ls's output with a program designed to highlight trailing blanks such as `ls -1 tftp* | cat -vet`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You either have trailing whitespace, or a corrupt filesystem.

Try

```
for i in tftp.plist*
do
    echo "'$i'"
done
```

That should output something like

```
'tftp.plist'
'tftp.plist '
```

note the quotes and the extra space. If it outputs the exact same thing twice, you likely have a corrupt filesystem.

Try

```
ls -i tftp.plist*
```

this will give you the inode numbers of the file. If they're the same, you have the same file twice in your directory. That would be Really Bad(tm), and you should run fsck asap. But I doubt that's the problem; it's more likely the whitespace thing.

Comment: Any idea why the trailing whitespace was not showing up using the `b` or `B` flags with 'ls`?

Comment: @datUser: `-B` is nothing to do with this, and you don't show an example of `ls -b`. However, with `-blah` you certainly should have seen a line ending tftp.plist\

Comment: Yeah i was using both `b` and `B` and neither show the escaped space or the value of the non-printing character in readable format. Very odd IMHO.

Comment: You can redirect the output of `ls` into a file, and check it with `less` or a text editor...

Comment: If the two files had exactly identical names, that would indeed have been a corrupt file system. But it couldn't have been the explanation, because if the files had in fact had identical names, then `ls` would have `stat` the same file name twice, and the result would have been that it had `stat` one file twice, not two different files. And we can see that it did `stat` two different files because they had different time stamps.

Comment: For those still wondering, the hexdump reveals the name is "tftp.plist " (that is, trailing space).

Comment: What's Really Bad(tm)?